# Lost connection with WD Passport. I can't read my files anymore

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, mbr

I have external WD Passport 4tb harddrive which I haven't used a lot. I plugged it in maybe 30ish times since I bough it less than 2 years ago. At some stage the USB connector became lousy and it started to lose the connection with my computer more and more often. Every time I had to find and keep the correct angle of the cable to make it work. And then it became almost impossible to set the right position where it can work. Unfortunately, just when I wanted to copy files from it, it became unreadable.

Somehow I can still manage to find the correct angle supporting the connector with something to make it not moving around, the LED shows that HDD is being properly initialised, but I can't see the files neither the letter assigned to it. I used some tools that helped me before to recover the files, but no luck this time. It shows me that MBR needs to be fixed and that I have 0 cyliders. Is it possible to get my data back?

Just to note that WD Passports are known for not having SATA connector, so I can't try to chuck it out and plug directly to my computer. Also there is a built-in encryption that prevents me just simply to replace the electronics. I tried with different cables as well.

Comment: Sounds like you're left with only two options - whether it's economical to get the socket replaced, or just bin it & buy something else.

Comment: @Tetsujin Well, I still have some data on it that I would like to save before I bin it, so I'm more for the first option. My only concern is that's not physical issue, but logical which can be fixed with a software. The hard drive is read, but not the data.

Comment: One sure-fire way to screw up a drive is for it to be intermittently connecting & disconnecting while it's trying to read & write data. You have a 3rd option; give it to a data recovery company.

Comment: "I plugged it in maybe 30ish times since I bough it less than 2 years ago. " - that's a lot. Maybe next time get something like [this](https://www.cablemonkey.co.uk/usb-cables/42116-usb-30-a-male-a-female-extension-cable-.html) if you absolutely have to keep unplugging it?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - or just don't be so rough with things;) I have devices & cables that must have gone through plug/unplug cycles in the hundreds or potentially thousands (some in commercial situations, 20 times a day)… all still working well. I have a partner who can destroy anything like an iPhone charger cable in 6 months. Decorum forbids I should say any more ;))

Comment: @MichaelHarvey
That's not a lot. I used that hard drive as way to transfer files between 2 computers. These are made to be poratble. I have, for example, WD Elements 1TB I bought in 2014/2015. I used it countless of times. And never had any issues with it.

Lousy contacts on electronics are the only reason for this.

Comment: The original USB specification stated 1500 mating cycles. You were unlucky.